# mpdf works in cli but not in browser

Tags: php, mpdf

I have just installed mpdf on my Ubuntu Server 16.04. I'm using the sample Hello World script that works fine in cli and generates a pdf saying Hello World. But when I try to execute the same php script in a browser nothing happens.

I have searched for this problem without being able to find any similar problem or solution.

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the environment the php script is executed in (e.g. http server software)? Also could you specify "nothing happens"? Are you getting http response/error, blank page, ...?

Comment: I am running Apache. I get a blank page as the result.

Comment: Have you verified that the user that is running apache has the appropriate rights to write a file at the location of your script? Also please check your apache and php log files and update your question.

Comment: Problem solved. I looked in the php log file. It was a permission problem in the mpdf folder. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Maybe you could share your solution for other users ;)

Comment: I used 777 as permission on the mpdf folder, this is possibly not the correct way but it solved my problem because this is only a development server.